# Changing AsyncValidator's response in angular 4

Tags: angular, rxjs, observable

`AsyncValidators` requires `Observable` as retrun type.
`http` request is `Observale` but my server returns `true` or `false` not `{uniqeTitle:true}` or `null` value as angular wants.

I have to create my own observable... with no luck.

Here what I have

```
static uniqeTitle(fieldControl: FormControl): Observable<any> {
    const subject = new Subject<any>();
    apiService.get('online-validation/')
        .subscribe(resp => {
            subject.next(resp?null:{uniqueTitle:true});
        });
    return subject;
}
```

Edit: I need complete!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use `map` to transform the value and return the mapped observable instead of creating a new one:

```
static uniqeTitle(fieldControl: FormControl): Observable<any> {

    return apiService.get('online-validation/')
        .map(resp => {
            return resp?null:{uniqueTitle:true});
        });

}
```